# React Router v4 Navigate from MobX store action?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, mobx

I am trying to have react router v4 navigate from an action in a `store` without explicitly passing the `history` prop to each store action that needs to navigate after some logic runs.

I am looking for something like this to work:

```
import { NavigationStore } from 'navigation-store';

class ContactStore {
  @action contactForm(name, message){
    // Some logic runs here

    // Then navigate back or success

    // Go back
    NavigationStore.goBack();

    // Or Navigate to Route
    NavigationStore.push('/success'); 
  }
}
```

Of course `NavigationStore` doesn't exist (I wouldn't know what to put in it from React Router to make it work), but I am looking to import a mobx navigation store that I can use to navigate to and from anywhere in the app (component or store) with the same api as `react-router`

How to do it?

**Update:**

RR4 doesn't give us a way to navigate from a store's action. I am trying to navigate **just like above** using RR4. I just need to know what `navigation-store` should contain to so I can:

1. `import { NavigationStore } from 'navigation-store';` anywhere (component/store), also history aware, to be able to navigate from anywhere.
2. `NavigationStore.RR4Method(RR4MethodParam?);` where `RR4Method` would be the available RR4 navigation options like push, goBack, etc.. (This is how navigation should happen)

**Update 2:**

So the url updates now from the `NavigationStore.push('/success');` but no webpage refresh happens.

Here is `navigation-store.js`

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx'
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

class NavigationStore {
  @observable location = null;
  history = createBrowserHistory();

  @autobind push(location) {
    this.history.push(location);
  }
  @autobind replace(location) {
    this.history.replace(location);
  }
  @autobind go(n) {
    this.history.go(n);
  }
  @autobind goBack() {
    this.history.goBack();
  }
  @autobind goForward() {
    this.history.goForward();
  }
}

const navigationStore = new NavigationStore();

export default navigationStore;
```

Here is `app.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Contact from 'screens/Contact'
import Success from 'screens/Success'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Provider>
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
              <Route path='/success' component={Success} />
            </div>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Once the url changes to `/success`, nothing happens to the webpage instead of loading the matching component `Success` in this case. Still stuck here..

**Update 3 (solution):**

[This helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510528/485961) I am putting it here as a reference for others as it was very frustrating for me.

In `app.js` I had to change:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
<Router>
```

to

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import navigationStore from 'stores/navigation-store'
<Router history={navigationStore.history}>
```

I hope this helps others :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use a store as a constructor argument to another store. Then you'll be able to use the `NavigationStore` instance correctly.

So where you initialize your stores you can have:

```
const navigationStore = new NavigationStore(); 
const contactStore = new ContactStore(navigationStore)
const stores = {
    navigationStore, 
    contactStore
}
```

And then your contact store becomes:

```
class ContactStore {
  _navigationStore; 
  constructor(navigationStore) {
    this._navigationStore = navigationStore;
  }
  @action contactForm(name, message){
    // Some logic runs here

    // Then navigate back or success

    // Go back
    this._navigationStore.goBack();

    // Or Navigate to Route
    this._navigationStore.push('/success'); 
  }
}
```

---

**Edit**

You can also [use a singleton](https://k94n.com/es6-modules-single-instance-pattern) in order to export the instance of the store, and thus use it by importing it in any module. So you could have something like this:

*navigationStore.js*

```
class NavigationStore() {
    goBack() {...}; 
    push(target) {...};
}
const navigationStore = new NavigationStore();
// The trick here is to export the instance of the class, not the class itself
// So, all other modules use the same instance.  
export default navigationStore;
```

*contactStore.js*

```
import navigationStore from 'navigation-store';
// We import the naviationStore instance here

class ContactStore {
  @action contactForm(name, message){
    // Some logic runs here

    // Then navigate back or success

    // Go back
    navigationStore.goBack();

    // Or Navigate to Route
    navigationStore.push('/success'); 
  }
}
```

*App.js*: Where you initialize the stores for the mobx provider:

```
import navigationStore from './navigationStore'; 
// We import the same instance here, to still have it in the provider.
// Not necessary if you don't want to inject it. 

const stores = {
    navigationStore, 
    contactStore: new ContactStore();
}
```

Comment: I basically want to import the store (like I posted) and use it to navigate with the store (that is history aware) without the constructor being involved. I just don't know what should go into it to have RR4 work. [Here](https://github.com/hotchpotch/react-navigation-mobx-example/blob/master/src/stores/NavigationStore.js) is an example for `react-navigation` but looking for the same with RR4. The reason is I have a RN app with `react-navigation` using the same code I posted/linked and I want to reuse the same syntax in my many actions that navigate from components/stores with RR4 for web.

Comment: Sorry it's unclear to me what you are asking. Could you maybe add more details to your question? Are you looking for a way to use either React-router 4 or Navigation Store depending on the platform? What's wrong with passing a store in the constructor?

Comment: A bit yes. Maybe you can directly achieving this using the `history` object? 
What I usually do is use mobx-react-router and pass the router store as a constructor argument to all other stores (or use the injected router in react components). If you prefer to go with a _single instance pattern_, it should work too.

Comment: I looked into `mobx-react-router` a few days ago but didn't see anyway where I can just import a `navigation-store` and navigate.. I feel like it should be so much easier to be able to navigate from a central store by importing it and navigating!

Comment: You can if you make this store a single instance that you export in a file. Like `export const navigationStore = new NavigationStore`

Comment: Can you show what the final code should look like to work?

Comment: Done. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks :) It helped a bit but still stuck. Added Update 2, I hope it's simple.

Comment: Added Update 3 with working solution, thanks for all you help :)

Comment: guys, your answers and conversations really helped me out. thank you!